# Dealing with Roundoff Error when writing RREF

Tags: java, matrix, rounding, linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a program that solves for the reduced row echelon form when given a matrix. Basically what I'm doing is writing a program that solves systems of equations. However, due to the fact that there are times when I need to do division to result in repeating digits (such as 2/3 which is .66666...) and java rounds off to a certain digit, there are times when a pivot should be 0 (meaning no pivot) is something like .0000001 and it messes up my whole program.

My first question is if I were to have some sort of if statement, what is the best way to write something like "if this number is less than .00001 away from being an integer, then round to that closest integer".

My second question is does anyone have any ideas on more optimal ways of handling this situation rather than just put if statements rounding numbers all over the place.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you are writing a program that solves systems of equations. This is quite a complicated problem. If you only want to use such a program, you are better off using a library written by somebody else. I will assume that you really want to write the program yourself, for fun and/or education.

You identified the main problem: using floating point numbers leads to rounding and thus to inexact results. There are two solutions for this.

The first solution is not to use floating point numbers. Use only integers and reduce the matrix to row echelon form (not reduced); this can be done without divisions. Since all computations with integers are exact, a pivot that should be 0 will be exactly 0 (actually, there may be a problem with overflow). Of course, this will only work if the matrix you start with consists of integers. You can generalize this approach by working with fractions instead of integers.

The second solution is to use floating point numbers and be very careful. This is a topic of a whole branch of mathematics / computer science called numerical analysis. It is too complicated to explain in an answer here, so you have to get a book on numerical analysis. In simple terms, what you want to do is to say that if Math.abs(pivot) < some small value, then you assume that the pivot should be zero, but that it is something like .0000000001 because of rounding errors, so you just act as if the pivot is zero. The problem is finding out what "some small value" is.